# Mostrar popup en ASP.NET para pedir contraseña

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validación, popup, onclick

Lo que quiero hacer es que la pagina me muestre un popup pidiendo password cuando el usuario de click a un boton, ya lo tengo mostrando un popup pero sin INPUTS ya que solo muestra un mensaje cualquiera, yo quiero que en lugar de eso te despliegue un INPUT para poder insertar la contraseña y valide junto con la base de datos, muchas gracias de antemano!

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>                          
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="AddButton" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('Hello World!');" runat="server" Height="15" ImageUrl="images/der_up.png"
                          CommandName="Actualizar" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" />                        
                      </ItemTemplate> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: inténtalo con `prompt()` en vez de `alert()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me ha servido pero ahora estoy en un dilema de como voy a hacer la validacion? No tendra alguna idea?